# $p$ divides $ax+by+cz$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, sumset

I am going to ask here a generalization of [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033002/19-divides-axbycz/2033841#2033841):

**Problem** Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let $p$ be a sufficiently large prime. Then, show that, for every $X\subseteq \{1,\ldots,p\}$ with $|X|\ge \varepsilon p$, there exist $a,b,c,x,y,z \in X$ such that $p$ divides $ax+by+cz$.

*Motivation*: I know a solution for this problem, but I feel that a simpler answer exists, as in the other case (which was just a pigenhole)

*Intuition for the result*: Usually a "large" subset of a finite field is not a proper subfield.

Comment: What exactly is the question??? Surely, a user with your reputation has been here long enough to know that an explicit question needs to be asked rather than linked.

Comment: Is your $\varepsilon$ a natural number? If not I can take it to be $1/p$ and I can pick $X$ with just one element and have a counterexample.

Comment: Well, I don't see any motivation (nor question) explicitly stated here. You're forcing any one reading this to open that linked question, which I think is not the right approach, but that's just my opinion...

Comment: @mathma If you want to be pedantic: "Fix a *real* $\varepsilon>0$, there there exists $p_0=p_0(\varepsilon)$ such that for every prime $p\ge p_0$, [etc]"

Comment: @barakmanos I had to be more explicit in the details, you're right. There should be everything now

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Ok so take $\varepsilon=1/p$ then $X=\{1\}$ has cardinality = $\varepsilon \cdot p$. The only sum of the shape you ask is $1+1+1=3$ and no prime other than 3 divides this.

Comment: @mathma No: *first* you fix $\varepsilon$, *then* $p$ has to be chosen sufficiently large; evidently $p=1/\varepsilon$ is not enough large ;)

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Ok, sorry I though $p$ was fixed.

Comment: It did occur to me as I was answering the $p=19$ specific question that we could probably lower the size of $X$ to $6$ or $7$.

Comment: @Joffan Do you mean that you have a different way to prove the stronger bound?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that; there was just so much choice available in the solution for which numbers to generate as the intermediate terms that it seemed very likely that the minimum size of $X$ is somewhat lower. On review of the options for $|X|=2$ just now, I now suspect the actual limit is $|X|=3$ or possibly $4$, since almost half of the $|X|=2$ subsets can deliver the desired result. I can probably prove this limit (whichever it is) by exhaustive search.